# Need to rescue 401 status code using RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I am using a Rails gem to send requests to an api using RestClient. I need to rescue a 401 error code. I saw the following on RestClient documentation:

```
> RestClient.get('http://my-rest-service.com/resource'){ |response,
> request, result, &block|   case response.code   when 200
>     p "It worked !"
>     response   when 423
>     raise SomeCustomExceptionIfYouWant   else
>     response.return!(request, result, &block)   end }
```

I have attempted to implement a similar case statement:

```
case response.code
 when 200
  JSON.parse(response.body)
 when 401
  raise AuthenicationError, "Unauthorized"
 else
  raise RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse
end
```

It captures the 200 case fine but ignores the 401 case and goes straight to the else. Any suggestions on raising an exception for 401 on a response that's coming back through RestClient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell you and why I'm sure the rest-client repo can tell you :) ... but using `RestClient::Request.new` then executing the api call with a block works for me. 
I think it probably has to do with the fact that the RestClient has built in exceptions.

```
request = RestClient::Request.new(
    method: :get,
    url: 'https://my-rest-service.com/resource.json')
response = request.execute {|response| response}
case response.code
  when 200
    puts "Good"
  when 401 
    puts "Bad"
    raise Exception
end
```

Answer (score 3):

> It captures the 200 case fine but ignores the 401 case and goes straight to the else.

I rather suspect it does *not* go to the else, actually; you'd still get a `RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse` raised even if you took out the else clause completely, because [that's what `RestClient.get` *does* when it gets an error response such as in the 400 or 500 range](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#exceptions-see-httpwwww3orgprotocolsrfc2616rfc2616-sec10html). From the README:

> - for result codes between 200 and 207, a RestClient::Response will be returned
> - for result codes 301, 302 or 307, the redirection will be followed if the request is a GET or a HEAD
> - for result code 303, the redirection will be followed and the request transformed into a GET
> - for other cases, a RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse holding the Response will be raised; a specific exception class will be thrown for known error codes
> - call .response on the exception to get the server's response

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong HTTP code. Unauthorized is actually 401, not 410.

Comment: Right sorry, I double checked my code and it is actually 401 in the case just had 410 on the mind when typing this question.

Comment: Are you sure that response's code is actually 401? Add 'puts response.code' before case statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the exception from `Request.execute` in a `rescue` block, note that you can also get the response body form the exception, example:

```
def request(method, url, params = {})
  resp = RestClient::Request.execute(
    method: method,
    url: url,
    timeout: 30,
    accept: :json,
    payload: params.to_json,
    headers: {
      content_type: :json,
    }
  )
  JSON.parse(resp.body)
rescue => e
  { error: e.message, body: JSON.parse(e.response.body) }               # <-------------
end
```